# Как программно можно заполнить поле  в WebBrowser C#?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как программно можно заполнить поле: `<input type="file"...>` в WebBrowser C#?  
Хотел сделать через WinAPI, но, может, есть другое решение?
В Интернете ничего найти не смог!

Comment: _"как программно можно заполнить поле"_ -- дождаться загрузку документа, после этого найти тег - GetElementsByTagName и SetAttribute(...). см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485816/196972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то в недрах WebBrowser есть свойство, содержащее код открытой страницы, если оно доступно для записи, то выдираешь код, редактируешь (например, через HtmlAgilityPack) и пихаешь обратно.

Comment: Спасибо! Но я, наверное, сделаю через WinAPI, т.к. эта страница использует JS для передачи данных серверу.