# Считывание полей на html странице

Tags: c#

Пишу одну программку(WinForms) для работы с сайтом.
Использую компонент `webBrowser`. Открывается html страница, там есть два поля ввода. Мне нужно сохранить введённые значения. Делаю это так:

```
if (webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString() == f_url)
{
    login = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").InnerText;
    password = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").InnerText;
}
```

Потом пользователь нажимает "Войти", html страница меняется, данные теряются.
Так как кнопка "Войти" находится на странице, я не могу хэндлить нажатие на неё.
Пробовал запускать в другом потоке при загрузке формы с `webBrowser`:

```
new Thread(SaveData).Start();
...
public void SaveData()
{
    while(true) {
        if (webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString() == f_url)
        {
            login = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").InnerText;
            password = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").InnerText;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Чтобы каждые 0.5 сек опрашивать состояние полей ввода(если открыт нужный url) независимо от того, что происходит на странице браузера. Но тогда у остального кода нет доступа к `webBrowser` и программа вылетает.

События `Navigated` и `Navigating` тоже не помогают, код в середине обработки этих событий не имеет доступа к `webBrowser.Document`

Что можно сделать?

Comment: _"кнопка "Войти" находится на странице, я не могу хэндлить нажатие на неё"_  -- а так `browser.Document.GetElementById("buttonId").Click += (s.e) => { ... };` не работает?

Comment: А какая цель всей этой затеи? Не исключено, что можно придумать более простой путь.

Answer (score 1):

Всё решилось событием `Navigating`.
Просто в моём случае его нельзя было использовать при запуске программы, так как `webBrowser.Document` пустой до загрузки первой страницы.
В самом событии я ввёл счётчик загруженных страниц и код считывания значений полей срабатывал, когда загружено > 0 страниц

Answer (score 0):

> кнопка "Войти" находится на странице, я не могу хэндлить нажатие на неё.

Подпишитесь на событие WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted -- вызывается при загрузке страницы и фреймов. Если страница загружена полностью, то значение свойства WebBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete

---

Например, есть страница, со следующим html

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="txt" value="123" />
    <input type="submit" value="войти" id="send" />
</form>
```

Создаем форму с WebBrowser, в который загрузим эту страницу

```
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;

var f = new Form();
var b = new WebBrowser() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
b.Navigating += (s, e) => {
   if (b.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
      var v = b.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0].GetAttribute("value");
      Console.WriteLine("Value: " + v);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Navigating: " + e.Url + " " + e.TargetFrameName);
};
b.Navigated += (s, e) => 
   Console.WriteLine("Navigated: " + e.Url);
b.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => {
   Console.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted: " + e.Url + " " + b.ReadyState);
   if(b.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
      b.Document.GetElementById("send").Click += (si, ei) =>
         Console.WriteLine("Click: send");
};
f.Load += (s, e) => b.Navigate("http://localhost:60927/home/test");
f.ShowDialog();
```

При загрузке получаем события

```
Navigating: http://localhost:60927/home/test 
Navigated: http://localhost:60927/home/test
DocumentCompleted: http://localhost:60927/home/test Complete
```

Если на странице нажать на кнопку "войти", то получим события

```
Click: send
Value: 123
Navigating: http://localhost:60927/home/test?txt=123 
Navigated: http://localhost:60927/home/test?txt=123
DocumentCompleted: http://localhost:60927/home/test?txt=123 Complete
```

Из лога событий видно, что нажатия кнопки перехватывается. А также после нажатия, в момент начала загрузки страницы, можно прочесть значения из полей ввода.

---

[Подписка и отмена подписки на события](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms366768.aspx).
[Использование лямбда-выражений вне LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb383984.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Я в C# новичёк, не могли бы указать, где почитать об этой форме записи функции `b.Navigating += (s, e) => {`? Это лямбда выражение(`=>`)?

Comment: @DimTeam _"Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ."_ -- пожалуйста. _"где почитать об этой форме записи форме записи"_ -- добавил в ответ две ссылки

Comment: @DimTeam _"Спасибо"_ -- можно нажать "ответ полезен" - это стрелка вверх слева от ответа. если вопрос закрыт, то отметьте ответ зеленой галочкой.

Comment: вы повторили мой ответ развёрнуто, за что я и поблагодарил, где зелёная галочка я знаю.

Comment: @DimTeam _"за что я и поблагодарил"_ -- понятно. вы поставили +1, но кто-то из минусаторов поставил -1, в итоге у ответа 0.